# URL to only redirect to language-specific URLs using HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE?

Tags: seo, redirects, internationalization, hreflang, accept-language

Before I begin, I am aware of https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites, but there I have a specific question which isn't answered there.

I have a website in German and English. There's an app download page accessible via:

```
https://example.com/download -> Redirects to en or de depending on HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE
https://example.com/en/download-app -> English
https://example.com/de/app-herunterladen -> German
```

FYI: There is an option to manually switch to the other language. I also have the following in my `<head>`:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/en/download-app" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/app-herunterladen" />
```

Since it looks nicer and is more flexible, I'd like to get backlinks mainly for .../download.

Is this bad practice? To have a ton of backlinks for a page that doesn't really exist, but only redirects?

Or should I instead have `https://example.com/download` as a third page that adapts its content depending on `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`? I would then add `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/download" />` to my `<head>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't horrible SEO practice, but it isn't ideal to have back links to a language redirect page.

Googlebot is only going to see one version of your redirect because it doesn't crawl with multiple `Accept-Language` headers. That version is probably going to be English because Google is a US based company. Google will see all of the PageRank pointing to `https://example.com/en/download-app` and your German download page won't rank well.

You should **not** have `https://example.com/download` as a third page that adapts its content depending on `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`.  That would be **even worse** for SEO.  Then Google would only see the English content plus you would have duplicate content issues.

The ideal situation would be to have links from English sites point to `https://example.com/en/download-app` and links from German sites point to `https://example.com/de/app-herunterladen` when possible. Then both pages get some link juice.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think I should still include `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/download" />`, even though it's "just" a redirect page? Just so that there is "some" context for Google when there is the occasional backlink to `.../download`.

Comment: No, you should not include that. Hreflang tags have to be symmetric. You can't put a hreflang tag on the redirect URL, so there shouldn't be any such tags pointing to it.